# Start spring boot on port 80

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, spring-boot, windows-10

Same question as [Spring Boot won't start on port 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016829/spring-boot-wont-start-on-port-80) but for windows.

How do I start spring boot on port 80 on Windows?  Specifically though, I'm running it with the maven command `spring-boot:run` from IntelliJ Community Edition.

Comment: have you tried setting the server.port value as mentioned in the linked post ? What is happening ? Does starting Spring Boot fail completely ? Is there a message ?

Comment: Yes, setting it to port 8080 works, but setting it to 80 does not.

Comment: Hi Carlos could you share a stacktrace or some log output? It will help identifying the issue.

Comment: You need root to be able to run on 80