# Executing without spring-boot:run failed

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I can't run my spring boot app simply with `java -jar` because it doesn't listen to the port. But if I run the same app with Intellij idea and spring boot maven plugin with command `spring-boot:run` its ok. Why?

Comment: [Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016829/spring-boot-wont-start-on-port-80) found: need to run `java -jar` with admin privileges

Comment: If that post answered your question, you should mark your question as duplicate of that one (it's the flag link at the bottom of your question).